# nested resources with shallow routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working with rails for a while but I have yet to overcome the problem of using 3 level deep nested resources. When I am on the notes page I would like to link course name to the class and course but rails keeps giving me an error.

I have 3 models class, course, and notes. A class has many courses and courses belong to a class. Course has many notes and note belong to a course. I will explain below.

**class.rb**

```
 has_many :courses
```

**course.rb**

```
belongs_to :class
has_many :schedules
has_many :notes, :through => :schedules
```

**note.rb**

```
has_many :schedules
has_many :courses, :through => :schedules
```

**schedule.rb**

```
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :note
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :classes, :shallow => true do
    resources :courses do
      resources :notes
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <% note.courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= note_class(course) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**notes_helper.rb**

```
  def note_class(course)
      link_to course.course_name, class_course_path(class, course)
  end
```

Shallow routes works great except when rails give me an error 'undefined local variable or method `class' for'. I think my code above is right but I am not sure why it is not working correctly. Any suggestions on how I can get the course to link to a url like so mysite.com/classes/1/course/3?

Comment: are you missing a `do` after `resources :courses`?

Comment: @PinnyM sorry about that but that is corrected in my routes.rb file

Comment: `class` is a keyword in ruby, perhaps try using something another name for your model that won't give you this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a while back but I figured since it hasn't been '*answered*', I'll give it a go.

Couple of things. First, the error you're getting inside the helper method is a result of not having a reference to the `class` instance. You're only passing the `course` object as a parameter. This would work given your associations above

**notes_helper.rb**

```
def note_class(course)
  link_to course.course_name, class_course_path(course.class, course)
end
```

Second, as mentioned in one of the comments, `class` is a reserved keyword in Ruby so it would serve you best to avoid using it for your models and associations. Cheers.